# Why is factoring causing wrong answer in resolution logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, unification

When performing resolution for the following KB:

```
1. Game(x) ^ Game(y) ^ Loves(z,x) => Loves(z,y)
2. Game(ResidentEvil)
3. Game(GodofWar)
4. Loves(John,GodofWar)
```

Query: Loves(John,ResidentEvil) ?

The answer should be true but when performing factoring it becomes false.

Resolve sentence 1 and query:

```
~Game(x) v ~Game(ResidentEvil) v ~Loves(John,x)
```

Now if we perform factoring (for Game literal) on the result we get

```
~Game(ResidentEvil) v ~Loves(John,ResidentEvil)
```

Since `~Loves(John,ResidentEvil)` is again part of the result this will eventually result in false.

Why is factoring causing the query to be false when it should be true?

Answer (score 1):

Factoring is sometimes necessary to obtain the empty clause, but it is just an *extra* inference.  That is, the original clause

$\neg Game(x) \lor \neg Game(ResidentEvil) \lor \neg Loves(John,x)$

does not get *replaced* by

$\neg Game(ResidentEvil) \lor \neg Loves(John,ResidentEvil)$

but rather the latter clause gets *added* to the clause set.

But in this case, the added clause does nothing for you, and it is the original clause (that is still there!) that eventually gets you to the empty clause.

Comment: ok but if I don't perform factoring always on the resolvent the size of the KB will keep increasing, isn't it?

Comment: @Raj Yes, the KB will keep increasing ... which intuitively makes sense: as you go along, you figure out more and more things ( i.e. Your knowledge keeps growing).